# Removing <u> character from text using Scrapy

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Vista 64 bit to run Scrapy. I am trialing scraping some text from this webpage and have managed to get most of the text cleaned up, removing line breaks and HTML tags. However  tags still seem to be included in the text output to Command Shell:

```
u' British Grand Prix practice results ', u'
```

This is from the following webpage:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/formula1/28166984
The above string represents a hyperlink to another page. I have tried using the following regular expression to remove the 'u' tags, but it has not worked:

```
body = response.xpath("//p").extract()
body2 = str(body)
body3 = re.sub(r'(\\[u]|\s){2,}', ' ', body2)
```

Can anyone suggest a way or removing these tags? Also, if possible, can you use regular expressions to remove everything between two  tags as well?

Thanks

Comment: Err, I believe the `u` there means the string is in unicode, and there seems to be another one you have removed with only the unicode indicator left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`u` is only python information that this text is coded in Unicode.

You have to print text in correct way to get it without this inforamtion.

```
a = [ u'hello', u'world' ]

print a

[u'hello', u'world']

for x in a:
    print x

hello
world
```

In you situation probably `body` is a list of strings

```
print type(body)
```

so do this

```
body2 = ''

for x in body:
    body += x

print body2
```

or even better:

```
body2 = "".join(body)

print body2
```

Comment: thats brilliant, thanks! i have been using several different steps to manually remove line breaks and carriage returns individually but your solution prints just pure text in two lines, which is just what i wanted.

Answer (score 3):

As furas mentioned, it is only displaying the encoding. By default, 2.7x uses ascii, so when a string is in unicode, it is denoted with a u. You can go back and forth using unicode and encode('utf-8')

```
>>> a = 's'
>>> a
's'
>>> a = unicode('s')
>>> a
u's'
>>> a = a.encode('utf-8')
>>> a
's'
```

Here's how to do it with a list

```
>>> ul = []
>>> ul.append(unicode('British Grand Prix practice results'))
>>> ul.append(unicode('some other string'))
>>> ul
[u'British Grand Prix practice results', u'some other string']
>>> l = []
>>> for s in ul:
...    l.append(s.encode('utf-8'))
...
>>> l
['British Grand Prix practice results', 'some other string']
>>>
```

Comment: when used your above syntax for switching back to ascii it gave a syntax error. i didnt specify in the above post though that I am printing to command shell at the minute using the command 'scrapy crawl myproject'. does command shell support ascii characters?

Comment: actually ignore, that...the syntax error was a rogue comma, however the unicode symbol is still being printed